# How to disable the address autocomplete for an input on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autocomplete, windows-10

I started with this solution:

```
<input autocomplete="off"/>
```

which worked for current safari and firefox, and some chromes. But then I am now trying to do this:

```
<input autocomplete="hello-<timestamp>-<randomnumber>"/>
```

That works for firefox, chrome, and safari on Mac, but not for windows. I only want to disable some of the inputs in a form, not all.

How do I get this to work on Chrome for Windows?

This is for a non-password field, like a phone number or username. I understand that you can't really disable autocomplete for passwords these days.

Comment: Is there more than one input in the form? Looks like Chrome will respect `autocomplete="garbage"` if you use a valid `autocomplete` on another input in the same form. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164

Comment: There are many inputs on the form.

Comment: Do any of them have valid `autocomplete` attributes?

Comment: No, they all have this format now.

Comment: Try setting one to `autocomplete="address-level4"`. I think Chrome's response will be to say, "Okay, this person isn't foolishly trying to disable all `autocomplete` attributes. Let's respect when they _do_ choose to disable some."

Answer (score 0):

Add to all fields `autocomplete="off"`. Then check which fileds still perform an autocomplete (for the address), and set the ones to `autocomplete="address-level4"` (thank you @michael crenshaw).

Also I found out, that the autocpmlete happens depending on the naming of the id of the input. So if you want to disable it just do not set the id (which probably isnt what you want depending on how you process the input, thus this is not really a good clean solution).